# On my Apache, how do I make sure that log file do not grow too large?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I noticed that my tomcat files grow to be A LOT, basically filling up my entire space.

I read about logrotate and I found the logrotate.conf file in /etc/. It currently looks like this:

But I would like to set up a daily or weekly task that basically prevents the my log files found in tomcat to grow to more than 1 GB for example.

Comment: Are you sure you need to log that much? In your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871537/catalina-out-file-from-tomcat-goes-up-to-32gb-every-week-how-to-limit-prevent-t) duplicate of this question you say that you log 32GB in one week. That's so much logging that in my experience it's about as useful as no logging at all.

Comment: I've voted for this question to be off topic for stackoverflow, but seeing the comment above afterwards, i wish I'd have voted for duplicate (I've also voted to close on that duplicate post for being off-topic). Both posts are configuration related, thus not a good fit for stackoverflow. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

Create a configuration file in the following path: /etc/logrotate.d/ . For example: /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat

```
/var/cache/tomcat7/catalina*.* {
   copytruncate
   daily
   rotate 7
   compress
   missingok
   size 100M
   }
```

This runs rotation after 100M, compresses the file, and keeps 7 days worth (rotate 7). copytruncate means that it'll copy then truncate the original file so that there is no need to restart tomcat.

Note: Please use your absolute path in the above example.

Comment: Every night the cron daemon runs jobs listed in the `/etc/cron.daily/` directory. This triggers the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file which is generally shipped with linux installations. It runs the command `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`.
The /etc/logrotate.conf includes all scripts in the `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory. This triggers the `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` file that you wrote in the previous step. 
Run the following command to run the cron job manually.
`/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf `